# net core application with IIS 502.5 error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

So this question is really strange for me as I have not figured it out so far, I have a client to whom I developed an application. The server side of the application is made using asp.net core 2.0 and I installed it on the server using this ip and this port:

```
192.168.50.116:3333
```

I used postman to check on the web API and using the address I got it working and the API endpoints gave me the responses I wanted. Now, I tried to use postman on the computer of the end user that would use the application and it was not working, the error was that 502.5 and in 99% of the cases I see here it points to installing the bundle which is installed and the application actually runs.

The application event viewer points to a weird error that has nothing to do with asp.net core. I ask for advice here as the IT personnel there has no idea on how to troubleshoot on their own applications.

I also tried using their DNS server as they pointed out with an address like this:

```
srvwebapp/plotAPI

srvwebapp/plotDashboard
```

Those are the 2 applications, the dashboard app is made on Angular 5 and it runs correctly but the other is not, it runs on the server and can be accessed via the IP given but not with the address given on either the server or outside computers.

Comment: "The application event viewer points to a weird error that has nothing to do with asp.net core" - Does that error happen every time you try and access the website?

Comment: To get better error messages, try enabling `stdoutLogEnabled` and setting `stdoutLogFile` in the `web.config` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log

Comment: will post the errors early tomorrow as I will return to keep working on this.

Comment: Ok I am getting this error when trying yo call the service from other PC on the network:

Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline ' ', ErrorCode = '0x80070057 : 0.

Comment: Have you installed the [.NET Core Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) on the server?

Comment: Yes, like i said, it works on the server. Using Postman btw.